# Using If/Then with Arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, function

Hi I'm trying to prepare an if/then statement for my program using arrays. However, I am receiving an error, below is my function definition.

Error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer array

```
char gradefn(float courseavg [7]){
 char lettergrade;
 if(courseavg>=90)(lettergrade='A');
 else if(courseavg>=80)(lettergrade='B');
 else if(courseavg>=70)(lettergrade='C');
      else lettergrade='F';

}//END OF GRADEFN
```

Hey I tried to use a for loop but I think I may have the syntax a little off?

```
// Below is my prototype 
char gradefn(float courseavg [7]); 

//Function Def. 
char gradefn(float courseavg[7]){ 
char lettergrade; 
for(int row=0; row<7; row++) if (courseavg>=90) (lettergrade='A');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are passing an array of seven items, not a single number, to the `gradefn`. You need to calculate the average, and then compare the result to the percentiles:

```
float total = 0;
for (int i = 0 ; i != 7 ; i++) {
    total += courseavg[i];
}
float avg = total / 7.0;
if (avg > 90) lettergrade = 'A';
else ...
```

Comment: Alternatively, use `std::accumulate` to sum them.

Comment: @chris This is nearly certainly a learning exercise targeted at students who did not start with the standard library yet. Using `aggregate` is what one should code in production, but then again one would not use fixed-size "plain" arrays for this, deciding in favor of a more flexible container, such as `std::vector`.

Comment: Well, at least it might get them to look at that and realize it exists. A big problem is not knowing a tool is there.